# Proof of the Unique Readability Theorem

Tags: solution-verification, propositional-calculus

So, I'm assuming that I have the language $L_p$ of propositional logic with the symbols $(,),\lnot,\to, A_0,A_1,\ldots$, where the last few symbols is a countable sequence of atomic formulas. I'm also told that these symbols are distinct and that no symbol is a subsequence of another symbol.

Then, I am told that atomic formula is a formula or if $\alpha$ is a formula, then $(\lnot \alpha)$ is a formula or if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are formulas, then $(\alpha \to \beta)$ is a formula. No other sequence of symbols is a formula.

Now, I want to prove that every formula of $L_p$ satisfies exactly one of the three conditions above.

---

Proof Attempt:

Let $\phi$ be a formula of $L_p$. If $\phi$ is an atomic formula, then we're done. Now, suppose that $\phi$ is not an atomic formula. Suppose also that $\phi$ satisfies neither of the other two conditions for forming formulas.

Then, $\phi$ is a finite sequence of symbols that differs from $(\lnot \alpha)$ or $(\alpha \to \beta)$ in at least one symbol. But then this is impossible because, then, it cannot be a formula. Hence, it has to satisfy at least one of these.

Now, suppose that it satisfies both of these. So, there exists a formula $\alpha$ such that $\phi$ can be written as $(\lnot \alpha)$ and there exist formulas $\beta$ and $\gamma$ such that $\phi$ can be written as $(\beta \to \gamma)$. However, this is impossible because it would imply that $\lnot \alpha$ and $\beta \to \gamma$ are subsequences of each other. In particular, it would mean that $\lnot$ is a subsequence of $\to$ or vice versa. This is impossible. Hence, $\phi$ can only satisfy one of these conditions. But that just means that $\phi$ satisfies exactly one condition and this proves the desired result. $\Box$

Does the proof work? If it doesn't, then why? How can I fix it?

Also, I had a few separate questions regarding the structure of this whole argument, regardless of whether it's right or wrong. So, I noticed that while I'm doing this argument, I'm sort of making use of an underlying, internal reasoning in order to prove something in logic.

That is, the deductive reasoning I'm using to get to the conclusion seems to be very different from the what deduction would mean in logic, even though I haven't actually conceptualized the logic that I'm using in the argument. So, my question is if this is valid or not? If it is, then why am I allowed to do this? If it isn't valid, then how do I formalize the logic that I am using in the argument? Or am I getting this wrong entirely and am not looking at things in the best way possible?

Comment: Bump haha, I would still not be opposed to getting some feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument for uniqueness needs a bit of work. First, you really ought to explain why we’re done if $\varphi$ is an atomic formula $A_k$: if $\varphi$ could also be written as $(\neg\alpha)$ or $(\alpha\to\beta)$, then $($ would be a subsequence of $A_k$, which is not the case.

More important, your argument that $\varphi$ cannot be decomposed both as $(\neg\alpha)$ and as $(\beta\to\gamma)$ isn’t correct: $\neg\alpha$ and $\beta\to\gamma$ being the same sequence does not imply that $\neg$ is a subsequence of $\to$ or vice versa. A correct argument could go like this:

> Suppose that $\varphi$ is both $(\neg\alpha)$ and $(\beta\to\gamma)$. This does **not** mean that ‘$\neg$ is a subsequence of $\to$ or vice versa’: it means that $\neg\alpha$ is the same string of symbols as $\beta\to\gamma$, so it means that $\neg$ is the first symbol of $\beta$, where $\beta$ is a formula. It’s easy to prove by induction that every formula that is not atomic begins with a left parenthesis, and $\beta$ is a formula, so either $\beta$ is $A_k$ for some $k$, or $\beta$ is $(\sigma$ for some string $\sigma$ of symbols in the language. And this is impossible, since $\neg$ is not a substring of any $A_k$, and neither of $($ and $\neg$ is a substring of the other.

Proving this, however, is not sufficient: you also need to show that $\varphi$ cannot be written as $(\neg\alpha)$ or as $(\beta\to\gamma)$ in two different ways. The first is easy: it’s clear that if $(\neg\alpha)=(\neg\alpha')$, then $\alpha=\alpha'$. If $\varphi$ contains at least two instances of $\to$, however, it’s conceivable that it can be written as $(\beta\to\gamma)$ and as $(\beta'\to\gamma')$, where $\beta\ne\beta'$ and $\gamma\ne\gamma'$, and in order to have unique readability, we need to rule out that possibility.

Without loss of generality we may assume that $\beta'=\beta\delta$ for some non-empty string $\delta$, so the strings $\beta\to\gamma$ and $\beta\delta\to\gamma'$ are identical. This means that $\beta$ is a formula, and $\delta$ begins with $\to$. Let $\delta$ be $\to\delta'$, so that $\beta'$ is $\beta\to\delta'$. Now $\beta'$ is a formula, and it’s clearly not atomic, so it must begin with a left parenthesis and end with the matching right parenthesis. But $\beta$ is also a formula, and we now know that it begins with a left parenthesis, so it must end with the matching right parenthesis. This is impossible: the left parenthesis at the beginning of $\beta\to\delta'$ cannot have two different matching right parentheses.<sup>1</sup> Thus, $\phi$ cannot be written in the form $(\beta\to\gamma)$ in two different ways, and we’re done.

<sup>1</sup> This parenthesis matching argument can be made more rigorous, but it does take a bit of work.

Comment: Oh wow, I can't believe that I goofed up that badly. I'll probably read your answer up till the part where you talk about the decomposition of $\phi$. I want to try and find a proof for that on my own and I'll compare that with your argument once I've given a good attempt. Thank you so much! Would it be too much trouble to ask you to have a look at another question that I posted on the same topic? (It's the last one that I posted).

Comment: @Abhi: You’re welcome! By all means try it on your own: I’m all in favor of that! I’ll take a look at the new one (though I should warn you that it’s been almost 50 years since I last looked at such things!).

Comment: Oh my gosh *50 years* is a long time, I can't even imagine living that long. 

Oh also, one other thing; would you happen to have any suggestions for a reference or something that can address the questions that I left at the bottom of my post above? I realize that maybe some of them were ill-formed so you can let me know if that's the case too. But I just want to try and find something that's addressing these questions in an approachable manner that will, at the very least, satiate me until I can get to the more advanced stuff/answers.

Comment: @Abhi: I’d say that you’re simply using ordinary mathematical reasoning to proving something that just happens to be about formal logic. You’re not working within some specified formal system, and there’s no reason to do so. Does that help?

Comment: Hmm in that case, we're separating the reasoning we're using in dealing with formal logic and the reasoning that we're creating with formal logic? In other words, say, for example, I'm proving some kind of implication in formal logic (like I just did with my most recent question). Then, that implication is strictly not the same as the $\to$ connective that is introduced within $L_p$ as a symbol?

Comment: @Abhi: Right. The connective is part of a formal system. What you’re doing in these problems is using ordinary mathematical reasoning to prove things about the syntax of that system.

Comment: Ohhh wow that makes a lot of sense. And obviously, we define $\land$, $\lor$ and so on in terms of, say, $\lnot$ and $\to$ in a way that makes sense (For example, $(\alpha \land \beta)$ was defined as shorthand for $(\lnot(\alpha \to (\lnot \beta)))$ and this is intuitively obvious if we are taking inspiration from earlier work done with truth tables. I assume this is also the same reason why it's not a problem to say "the set of all formulas of $L_p$", even though I would think that set theory would be something touched on after formal logic.

Comment: Because I guess another question I did have is how we actually know if the collection of all formulas of $L_p$ is actually, itself, a set. But again, I suppose that the set theory we're using is independent of what we're studying and what we're studying is just a formal system which can be studied using ordinary mathematical reasoning?

Comment: @Abhi: Set theory and formal logic have a somewhat incestuous relationship, but yes, one generally starts with a bit of formal logic before getting into formal set theory.

Comment: Alright thank you, I'll try to do way more research into this and see if I can ask more focused questions. I'll also leave you to looking at my latest question in peace (so sorry for bombarding you with these questions and thank you so much, Professor Scott).

Comment: @Abhi: Within axiomatic set theory one can formalize the notion of a formula of $L_p$ and prove that there is a set consisting precisely of those formal objects. In general there’s no real need to worry about such things at this stage: the informal notions that you need behave ‘properly’, so to speak. (And you’re very welcome.)